# Mounted partition has the wrong owner

Tags: linux-mint, mount, fstab

I am on Linux Mint 20, and I used the Disks GUI in order to mount my 4 NTFS partitions to their mount points. They are mounted indeed, and I can create or delete (no rubbish bin though, complete deletion only) files, but everything is owned by `root`, and I'm not able to change the permissions.

I have searched about this, and have found similar cases, with a lot of different suggested solutions. Being a beginner, and those hard drives being precious (I'm backing them up at the moment), I don't dare trying all these solutions without making sure they apply to my case.

Here is the content of my `/etc/fstab` regarding those four hard drives:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9A50DD2D50DD10BD /mnt/foo auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/7EEE2DE6EE2D9803 /mnt/bar auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/26E81EF7256571FE /mnt/baz auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/52EEB3D0EEB3AA9D /mnt/qux auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

What should I change to make sure I own those mounted directories and their content?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want specifically you to be the owner, try replacing `nosuid` with `gid=<group id>,uid=<user id>`. If you're the only user, the `gid` and `uid` are both likely to be `1000`. You can check both by calling `id`.

NTFS doesn't have directly UNIX-compatible permissions, so when you mount an NTFS partition, I believe it takes on the permissions of whoever mounted it. If you `sudo mount` (or in this case, have the kernel mount them from `/etc/fstab`), the owner gets set to `root` unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Also as a side-note, you don't need to specify `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>` if you want to mount by UUID. You can simply use `UUID=<UUID>`. But, six of one, half a dozen of the other. Just a handy tip. :-)

Comment: Thank you, it works! :)